# Automapper map to existing object stack overflow exception

Tags: exception, nhibernate, automapper, dto

i'm coding a restService who can update some datas in a database via Nhibernate.
The service receive DTO objects from a client.

I'm using Automapper to map my Dto to NhibernateObject.

The problem is my DTO class  reference itself. here an example :

```cs
public class UserDto
{
    public String Name{get;set;}
    public string Lastname{get;set;}
    public UserDto UserOwner{get;set;}
}
```

here's my BusinessClass

```cs
public class User
{
    public String Name{get;set;}
    public string Lastname{get;set;}
    public String Adress{get;set;}
    public User UserOwner{get;set;}
}
```

Sometimes User object and UserOwner properties references the same object.

So when i do that

```cs
User usr = Automapper.Mapper.Map<UserDto,User>(myUserDtoObject); // this works fine
```

but when i do

```cs
Automapper.Mapper.Map(myUserdtoObject,MyUserNhibernateObject); // i've got a stackoverflowexception
```

I can use the first option but if i do that, when my new UserEntity returned by Map function is created the value of "Adress" properties is not set (UserDto does not contains it).

Comment: You could try using `Ignore` in the mapping definition and then assigning `UserOwner` manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MaxDepth - AutoMapper doesn't know how far to go down your rabbit hole.

```
ForMember(dest => dest.UserOwner, opt => opt.MaxDepth(1))
```

This is important for NHibernate, which uses proxy objects to load indefinitely. The other option is to ignore the UserOwner member, but that's likely not your intent here.

Comment: I tried this but after mapping the value of my UserOwner property is set to null.